# Как определить, пересекаются ли два прямоугольника, прямоугольники могут быть повёрнуты, как угодно, координаты точек каждого прямоугольника известны

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как определить, пересекаются ли два прямоугольника, прямоугольники могут быть повёрнуты, как угодно, координаты точек каждого прямоугольника известны

Comment: Попарно проверить стороны прямоугольников на пересечение.

Comment: И не забыть случай когда один прямоугольник целиком лежит в другом (если это тоже считается пересечением)

Comment: можноже сжульничать и сделать в pygame Rect.colliderect() ?

Comment: @Интик вроде-же `pygame.Rect` вращать нельзя?

Comment: не уверен, потому и в форме вопроса

Answer (score 1):

функция проверки пересечение двух отрезков:

```
def f(p0, p1):
    v1 = (p1[1][0]-p1[0][0])*(p0[0][1]-p1[0][1])-(p1[1][1]-p1[0][1])*(p0[0][0]-p1[0][0])
    v2 = (p1[1][0]-p1[0][0])*(p0[1][1]-p1[0][1])-(p1[1][1]-p1[0][1])*(p0[1][0]-p1[0][0])
    v3 = (p0[1][0]-p0[0][0])*(p1[0][1]-p0[0][1])-(p0[1][1]-p0[0][1])*(p1[0][0]-p0[0][0])
    v4 = (p0[1][0]-p0[0][0])*(p1[1][1]-p0[0][1])-(p0[1][1]-p0[0][1])*(p1[1][0]-p0[0][0])
    return (v1*v2<0) and (v3*v4<0)
```

Далее как сказал [@Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor)

> Попарно проверяем стороны прямоугольника на пересечение.